# Returning integers through if-statments

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm trying to take a set of 3 integers from a function, then pass it to another function then have it return them to the main function stating which of the 3 integers are the largest, my issue is that I keep getting it to print all 3 integers. The below code is what I have, im pretty sure the error is in the >def max3 function.... I am aware that the print is statement in the def main function is also incorrect

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print (x)
    print (y)
    print (z)

def max3(x,y,z):
    number1 = x
    number2 = y
    number3 = z
    if x > y < z:
        return (x)
    if y > x < z:
        return (y)
    if z > y < x:
        return (z)



main()
```

Comment: also, your logic is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print("The max is " + str(max3(x, y, z)))

def max3(x, y, z = None):
    if (z == None):
        if (x > y):
            return x
        else:
            return y
    else:
        maxNum = max3(x, y)
        if (maxNum > z):
            return maxNum
        else:
            return z
```

Alternatively, use the built in `max()` function:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print("The max is " + str(max(x, y, z)))
```

Comment: The only issue with that is if you leave a duplicate number for any two its gonna give an error

Comment: @user3331010 I found the error and updated both examples above.

Answer (score 0):

call max3 from main! Also, your logic for finding the largest number is wrong. You can find my solution. You can also try list.append() and use max() to find the largest number from that list.

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print (x)
    print (y)
    print (z)

    print (max3(x,y,z))


def max3(x,y,z):
    largest = z
    if (x > y and x > z):
        largest = x
    elif(y > z):
        largest = y

    return largest



main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you wrote, the function `max3` never gets used. Perhaps you want to call this function from `main`?

```
def main():
    ...
    max3(x,y,z)
```

Where the `...` represents the inputs and any printing that you want to do.

I think you should also try out some numbers at the python prompt. For example:

```
x=4.5
y=4
z=5
x>y<z
```

What is the result? Is this what you expected? You can pair two conditionals with an `and`:

```
x=0.2
x<1 and x>0
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

In main function you're getting x,y,z variables and printing all of them. not asking max3 function to return maximum. That's why it's printing all of them.

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print (x)
    print (y)
    print (z)
```

In max3 function you're supposed to return maximum, but it's not returning maximum. Also this function is not guaranteed to return some value.

```
def max3(x,y,z):
    number1 = x
    number2 = y
    number3 = z
    if x > y < z: # this line should check if x is maximum, so condition is like: y < x > z
        return (x)
    if y > x < z: # this too
        return (y)
    if z > y < x: # this too
        return (z)

main()
```

Corrected version:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    y = int(input("Another: "))
    z = int(input("Another: "))
    print max3(x,y,z)

def max3(x,y,z):
    number1 = x
    number2 = y
    number3 = z
    if y <= x >= z:
        return (x)
    if x <= y >= z:
        return (y)
    if x <= z >= y:
        return (z)

main()
```